# Javascript says my class method is not a function, even though it clearly is

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to implement a genetic algorithm using node and I looked at the other question posted here, and it seems unrelated.  When I try to call the `determine_fitness` method of my `populant` class I get this error:

```
Creating new population

Starting iteration 1
/home/aaron/Documents/workspace/playground/screeps_ga/ga.js:116
            p.determine_fitness();
              ^

TypeError: p.determine_fitness is not a function
    at population.fitness (/home/aaron/Documents/workspace/playground/screeps_ga/ga.js:116:15)
    at population.train (/home/aaron/Documents/workspace/playground/screeps_ga/ga.js:130:18)
```

I'm really new to javascript, so I'm not sure what to do here besides just follow the stacktrace and it's not giving me any answers.

But, when I look at my classes:

```js
class populant {
    constructor(genes) {
        this.genes = genes;
        this.score = -1;
    }

    mutate() {
        if(this.genes.length == 0)
            this.genes += random_char();
        else {
            let r = getRndInteger(0, 3);
            let i = getRndInteger(0, this.genes.length);
            switch(r) {
                case 0:
                    // Remove a character
                    let before = this.genes.substring(0, i);
                    let after = this.genes.substring(i + 1);
                    this.genes = before + after;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // Replace a character
                    let c = random_char();
                    let before = this.genes.substring(0, i);
                    let after = this.genes.substring(i + 1);
                    this.genes = before + c + after;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // Add a character
                    let c = random_char();
                    let before = this.genes.substring(0, i);
                    let after = this.genes.substring(i);
                    this.genes = before + c + after;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    mate(other, mutate) {
        let i = 0;
        let temp = '';

        for(i = 0; i < this.genes.length; i++)
        {
            if(getRndInteger(0, 2) == 0)
                temp += other.genes.substring(i, i + 1);
            else
                temp += this.genes.substring(i, i + 1);
        }

        this.genes = temp;

        if(mutate)
            this.mutate();
    }

    determine_fitness() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's very clearly defined here, and it doesn't conflict with any of my other property names, so I'm really confused.

```js
class population {
    constructor(count, mutation_rate, populant_type) {
        this.count = count;
        this.mutation_rate = mutation_rate;
        this.populant = populant_type;
        this.pop = [];
    }

    initialize(parent_pool) {
        this.pop = [];

        if(parent_pool.length == 0)
            for(let i = 0; i < this.count; i++)
                this.pop.push(new this.populant(random_gene()));
        else if(parent_pool.length == 1)
            for(let i = 0; i < this.count; i++)
                this.pop.push(new this.populant(parent_pool[0].genes));
        else
        {
            for(let i = 0; i < this.count; i++)
            {
                let pai = getRndInteger(0, parent_pool.length);
                let pbi = getRndInteger(0, parent_pool.length);
                let temp_pa = new this.populant(parent_pool[pai].genes);

                let should_mute = Math.random() < this.mutation_rate;
                temp_pa.mate(parent_pool[pbi], should_mute);
                this.pop.push(temp_pa);
            }
        }
    }

    fitness() {
        for(let p in this.pop)
            p.determine_fitness();
    }

    select_parents(count) {
        this.pop.sort(function(a, b){ return a.score - b.score; });
        return this.pop.slice(0, count);
    }

    train(iterations, crossover_size, initial_parents) {
        let selected_parents = initial_parents;

        for(let i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            this.initialize(selected_parents);
            this.fitness();
            selected_parents = this.select_parents(crossover_size);
        }

        return selected_parents;
    }
}
```

The way that I have the classes organized right now is that the `populant` class and the `population` class are in their own file `ga.js` and then I import them into my `test.js` file. Because the `determine_fitness()` method of `populant` isn't defined by default, I created a child class and overwrote it as seen below:

```js
let ga = require('./ga');

class StringPop extends ga.populant {
    constructor(genes) {
        super(genes);
    }

    determine_fitness() {
        let sum = 0;
        for(let i = 0; i < this.genes.length; i++)
            sum += this.genes.charCodeAt(i);
        this.score = sum;
        return sum;
    }
}
```

And then I'm testing the structure as shown:

```js
pop = new ga.population(20, 0.25, StringPop);

let iteration = 1;
let parents = []
while(true)
{
    console.log('\nStarting iteration ' + iteration.toString());
    parents = pop.train(1, 5, parents);

    console.log('Population after iteration');
    print_pops(pop);
}
```

Where `print_pops()` just prints out the `genes` property of each populant on their own line.

Comment: What happens if you compile this using TypeScript's `tsc`?

Comment: Where in the code you've posted is `ga.js`, line 116?

Comment: `ga.js` is the combination of both `populant` and `population`

Comment: Okay, I've tried to get `tsc` working, but I can't seemt to figure it out, I looked [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to check if the type of p is what you expect by logging it before trying to call determine_fitness:

```
fitness() {
    for(let p in this.pop) {
        console.log(typeof p);
        p.determine_fitness();
    }    
}
```

Also, since pop is a list and I think you push an object to it, you could use for ... of syntax:

```
fitness() {
    for (p of this.pop) {
        p.determine_fitness();
    }
}
```

From the [MDN article on for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> Given that for...in is built for iterating object properties, **not recommended for use with arrays**, and options like Array.prototype.forEach() and for...of exist, what might be the use of for...in at all? [Emphasis mine]

Comment: Using the `for(p of this.pop)` worked, apparently using `for(p in this.pop)` was causing p to be a serialized string???

Comment: To be honest, I don't perfectly understand how for ... in works and its use cases, I just know that when you want to get each element of a list in a loop for ... of is a good solution.

Comment: @LucasDeAngelis `for … in` is enumerating the property names of an object. It should not be used on arrays.